# Как подсчитать в столбце?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

У меня есть таблица в базе. В ней есть колонка, в которой находится ответы Yes, No. Скажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью SQLachemy подсчитать количество Yes, NO

```
    all_info['ask_six'] = Result.query(func.count('No')).select_from(Result.ask6).scalar()
```

All_info - это словарь, который содержит все данные из базы( средний возраст и т.д)

Result - это класс, который описывает таблицу. ask6 - это колонка, которая содержит 'Yes', 'No'

Comment: С чем именно у вас возникли затруднения? По правилам форума принято приводить собственную попытку решения в вопросе...

Comment: Я пробывала через query.count, но запуталась, где нужно указывать таблицу, где колонку и где фильтр

Comment: Приведите в вопросе попытку решения. Разумеется она будет неудачной или неправильной, иначе вы бы не задавали здесь вопрос... PS да и минимальный код для воспроизведения явно не помешал бы

Comment: all_info['ask_six'] = Result.query(func.count('No')).select_from(Result.ask6).scalar()